# Where is an error in mongo db validation sheme crossing?

Tags: c#, database, mongodb

I make a correct request to my mongo db collection and the request can't cross through my validation, but all types match. Where is a problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luj3V.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1o93.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Urw.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSZfg.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/378QS.jpg)

I've tried switch "long" type to "Int64" in validation scheme but problem is still existing. And make all types string, there also nothing.

Comment: See : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/kerberos/ and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/troubleshoot-kerberos/

Comment: do not post links and use plain text instead. Also, I do not understand your question

Comment: It would be good if you included the images as code examples instead.